# C# - Awesomium web browser - pixelated text on zoom

Tags: c#, svg, awesomium

I'm using awesomium web browser and a [D3 collapsible tree](http://mbostock.github.io/d3/talk/20111018/tree.html).  The tree uses SVG for everything, but when I set up zoom using [this API](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Zoom-Behavior), any zooming in causes the text to be drawn very pixelated.  Any text that collides with another element causes the colliding part to be drawn pixelated, as well.  I tried out my exact same code in Chrome, and it scales fine.  I can figure out what I could do to fix this issue.  Help?

Answer (score 1):

Apparently this is just something that happens with Awesomium.  Chromium may do better, but I won't be able to test that out.

Comment: You may want to leave this question unanswered, in hopes that someone that will eventually give it a real answer.  I have a similar problem :(